# How to map a foreign key with hibernate?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am writing an online store using `Spring Boot` (`MVC`) and `hiberbate`. I have an order class where I need a `Сart` link. But the problem is that in the database I do not have a specific `Сart` table, but there is a `cart _products` table, where the `peimary key` consists of two columns (as shown in the picture below!). I really need a connection in the `Order` class, so I decided to make a `Composite Primary Key` at the hibernate level (and I seem to have done it), but I can't figure out what to do next! I am stuck. Please tell me where to go? How can I solve my problem?

OrderClass:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_order")
public class Order {

    // Fields
    //
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    private String address;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_order")
    private Date dateOrder;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "order_status")
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;

    @Column(name = "total_cost")
    private BigDecimal totalCost;

    // Relationships
    //
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

//    @OneToMany
//    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_products_pkey")
//    private Cart cart;
}
```

Cart:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart_products")
public class Cart {

    @Embeddable
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class CartId implements Serializable {

        private Long orderId;

        private Long drinkId;
    }


    // Fields
    //
    @EmbeddedId
    private CartId cartId;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "drink_id")
    private Drink drink;

    private int count;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need access to the 'DRINKS' for that order. You need to change the relation to Cart from the Order class.

You have commented a relationship where ORDER just have access to one CART, since you need to access N CARTS (One to Many) you need to add a SET. Something like this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "cart_products_pkey")
private Set<Cart> cartProducts;
```

Now the ORDER has a SET of CART.

You can easily access to the CARTS of that ORDER with `order.getCartProducts()`

And since CART has a key to DRINK, you can easily access it.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Okey, but in table `pg_order` I havn't `cart_products_pkey`. This pkey is in table `cart_products`. How I can join this column from `Order`?

Comment: If there is no relationship, you can create the QUERY from CART_PRODUCTS, with the ORDER_ID.

Using JPA should be like

`// Cart repository class
List<Cart> findAllByOrderId (Long id)`

So now you can add that list to the Order class (extra attribute with no DB relation) or simply access to DRINK one by one